# How to get menu location in wp_update_nav_menu hook

Tags: plugins, menus, themes, hooks, actions

I want to get the menu location in the `wp_update_nav_menu` (during menu save action)

```
  add_action('wp_update_nav_menu', function ($id, $data = NULL)
    {
        error_log( var_export($data, true) );

    }, 10, 2);
```

However, the data only contains the `menu-name`, so how can I get the menu location?

Answer (score 3):

`get_nav_menu_locations` will give you menu IDs keyed by location which should correspond to the `$id` also passed with `wp_update_nav_menu`.

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu', function ($id, $data = NULL){

    foreach( get_nav_menu_locations() as $location => $menu_id ){
        if( $id == $menu_id ){
            echo 'location is ' . $location;
        }
    }

}, 10, 2);
```